# Content overflows from div with 100% height

Tags: html, css

When I view this page in Chrome, Firefox, or IE11, I notice upon horizontally resizing the window to its minimum width causes an overflow of text out of the white background div at the bottom of the page. The div is set to a height of 100%, so should it not continue to match the height of the page? It may seem the 100% matches the height of the window only, but upon initially loading the page in Chrome I see the white div causes a scroll bar such that there is more white space extended beyond on the height of the window.

I tried putting `overflow: auto;` in the #main css and the div ended up with a scroll bar. I removed it as it's not a solution I can accept. How can I get the div to accommodate its content automatically?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    html { 
        background: url('http://losingmedotorg.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/two-roads-in-a-wood.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
        background-size: cover;     
    }
    #main {
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-right: 20%;
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 10%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>The Road Not Taken</h1>
        Two roads diverged in a yellow wood, And sorry I could not travel both And be one traveler, long I stood And looked down one as far as I could To where it bent in the undergrowth; Then took the other, as just as fair And having perhaps the better claim, Because it was grassy and wanted wear; Though as for that the passing there Had worn them really about the same, And both that morning equally lay In leaves no step had trodden black. Oh, I kept the first for another day! Yet knowing how way leads on to way, I doubted if I should ever come back. I shall be telling this with a sigh Somewhere ages and ages hence: Two roads diverged in a wood, and I - I took the one less traveled by, And that has made all the difference.
        <p>- Robert Frost</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but I don't see any scrollbars when resizing http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwWNeJ

Comment: @jessikwa I removed the overflow: auto - it's not a solution I can accept.

Comment: @jessikwa In your codepen I do not see the same problem. Where I do see it is when the page is created in an html file and viewed locally in a browser.

Comment: 1) the text will overflow only horizontally **if** the word is wider than the white container. 2) Vertically the text will not overflow the white container. What's the min width you expect from a device?? Now can you explain again your issue? Thx. (Here's a jsBin I've created after reading your question: http://jsbin.com/suyafa/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`padding` will mess up `height: 100%`. It seems to calculate the height and then add the padding so the resulting height is actually closer to 120%. I tried this code in a local html file and it seems to do the trick.

Try this instead:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    html { 
        background: url('http://losingmedotorg.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/two-roads-in-a-wood.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
        background-size: cover;     
    }
    #main {
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-right: 20%;
        background-color: white;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #content {
        padding: 10%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <h1>The Road Not Taken</h1>
            Two roads diverged in a yellow wood, And sorry I could not travel both And be one traveler, long I stood And looked down one as far as I could To where it bent in the undergrowth; Then took the other, as just as fair And having perhaps the better claim, Because it was grassy and wanted wear; Though as for that the passing there Had worn them really about the same, And both that morning equally lay In leaves no step had trodden black. Oh, I kept the first for another day! Yet knowing how way leads on to way, I doubted if I should ever come back. I shall be telling this with a sigh Somewhere ages and ages hence: Two roads diverged in a wood, and I - I took the one less traveled by, And that has made all the difference.
            <p>- Robert Frost</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found an alternative solution - add `display: table;` to the `#main` selector and it totally works. However, I suspect yours is the better approach. I can read about table display elsewhere, but off the top of your head do you know any reason why I should avoid display: table in this case?

Comment: I honestly don't know it well enough to give you a lot of good reasons. From my understanding, one draw back is that it's not supported by some older browsers. You can check **[here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)** for compatibility. Also **[this site](https://2002-2012.mattwilcox.net/archive/entry/id/1030/)** offers a controversial argument as to why `display: table` is not a good idea. Again I don't know enough about it to agree or disagree with him but maybe it'll help you with your decision. Hope that helps! =)

Comment: Those are two great reasons, and I still think your approach is best. Thanks for getting back to me. Take care.