# Content overflows from 100% height DIV

Tags: html, css, overflow, flexbox

I want to make a `div` which:

1. Stretches to 100% `width` and `height` of browser window,
2. Makes all content inside centered vertically and horizontally,
3. Has `min-height` = all content + `10%` of `top`&`bottom` `padding`.

I've made some code:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.blah {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10% 0 10% 0;
  background: #ffb3b3;
}
```

```html
<div class="blah">
  <p>Here goes some content</p>
</div>
```

The same on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74rp069n/)

As you can see, it works fine, except **point 3** - when scaling down, the content overflows the `div` around it:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0urEC.png)

I've tried to set for `.blah`:

```css
height: auto;
min-height: 100% !important;
position: relative;
```

but then it doesn't work on bigger resolutions - `div` is bigger than the browser `height`.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829311/content-overflows-from-div-with-100-height) doesn't work.

I will be extremely grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to use `box-sizing:border-box`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
.blah {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffb3b3;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 10% 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="blah">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed maximus rhoncus erat sit amet ullamcorper. Cras quis vulputate ex, ut sollicitudin massa. Vivamus vitae ipsum posuere, eleifend quam quis, pulvinar tellus. Cras semper, lectus sit amet molestie
  
</div>
```

Comment: An explanation of *why* this fixes it would be quite useful